# Асинхронная подгрузка изображений при запуске проекта React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть .json-файл, который хранит в себе объекты следующего вида:

```
{ 
  id: number,
  photo: string,
  name: string
}
```

Размер файла 5мб и если подгружать его в момент отображение - то это заметно замедляет отрисовку компоненты.
Вопрос: как реализовать асинхронную подгрузку этого файла при запуске проекта, а не в момент рендеринга компоненты, которая перебирает и отображает изображения списком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может сделать цикл который будет запускаться при парсинге json и устанавливать на каждой итерации setState(), например:

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

fetch('url').then((res) => res.json().forEach((item) => setList((prev) => [...prev, item])));

return (<ul>{list.map((item) => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}</ul>)
```

Идея заключается в том чтобы отрисовывать компоненты списка до того как распарсятся все записи.